# Limit filterable attributes on top level categories

Tags: magento, attributes, categories, layered-navigation

I am building a Magento store with four layers of categories as follows.

```
Western Wear (Root Category)
-Men's
--Boots
---Western
---Work
---...
--Apparel
---Shirts
---...
--...
-Women's
--Boots
---Western
---Work
---...
--Apparel
---Shirts
---...
--...
-...
```

I've set up my attributes such that the customer may filter by attribute based on what I think makes sense from 3rd level category (e.g. Western Wear -> Men's -> Boots) perspective.

The problem is that if one were to navigate to one of the 2nd level categories, say the Men's category, he/she would be presented with a large amount of attributes for filtering, most of which are inappropriate at this level.

For these 2nd level categories (e.g. Men's and Women's), I would like to limit the number of filterable attributes that are displayed in layered navigation without losing the ability to filter by the "hidden" attributes in subcategories.

Continuing with the example, I want attributes such as Brand available in layered navigation while shopping in the Western Wear -> Men's category but not attributes such as Toe (from the Boot attribute set) or Sleeve_Type (from the Shirt attribute set).  Moreover, I want the attribute Toe available in layered navigation while shopping in the Western Wear -> Men's -> Boots category; and, I want the attribute Sleeve_Type available in layered navigation while shopping in the Western Wear -> Men's -> Apparel category.

I've searched Google for hours, but cannot find the answer.  I'm still very new to Magento, so I would appreciate detailed answers.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

What you want done here could be a major workaround in magento, overriding the core layered navigation functionality, a cleaner and easier way I reckon would be to use CSS to hide filters you do not want at the second level category pages, this should be simple and quick.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I'm really new to this.  Can you point me in the right direction?  What would the code look like?  Would I place the code in the Custom Layout Update field in the Custom Design tab for that particular category in manage categories?